# Writer focus issue (?)

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, gnome-shell

In Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome-shell when opening new or existing files in LO Writer I have to click in the text field with the mouse to be able to type or to use keyboard shortcuts to work with the text. For instance, I want to search for text in a Writer file, I open it and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> nothing happens until I click somewhere in the text. Similarly, I cannot type in new files until I put the cursor on the file with the mouse. How do I get rid of this annoyance?